# AWS DMS FATAL_ERROR Error with replicate-ongoing-changes only

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-rds, database-migration, amazon-aurora, aws-dms

I'm trying to migrate data from Aurora MySQL to S3. Since Aurora MySQL does not support replicating ongoing changes from cluster reader endpoint, my source endpoint is attached to cluster writer endpoint.

When I choose full-load migration only, DMS works. However, i get error `Last Error Task 'courral-membership-s3-writer' was suspended after 9 successive recovery failures Stop Reason FATAL_ERROR Error Level FATAL` when i choose full-load + ongoing replication or ongoing replication.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This could be an error caused by - Replication instance class, you may need to upgrade it.

Comment: which one is the replication instance -- the source, target, or dms server?

Comment: it's the dms server

Comment: Hey @Mell, have you tried upsizing the replication instance? Did that work for you?